# Parametric formula for cubes as sum of three cubes

Tags: number-theory, integers

Is there any parametric formula to solutions of the equation 
$a^3+b^3+c^3=d^3$, where $a,b,c,d$ are all integers, yielding all such $(a,b,c,d)$ satisfying the equation? 
Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, there are parametric solutions, see [this MO-question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/138886/which-integers-can-be-expressed-as-a-sum-of-three-cubes-in-infinitely-many-ways). But it is not known how to obtain all solutions.

Comment: @Dietrich Burde Thanks so much. +1 for your detailed explanation to the problem.